# Spring AspectJ Exception: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am trying to write a Spring AspectJ with this pointcut 
execution(* com..*(..))

I am using

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

I've got the following exception:

```
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class pl.codeleak.services.SomeService]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

I've checked the internet and found that CGLIB can't proxy final classes or classes with no default constructor.

The only solutions I've found so far:

1. Update to Spring 4
2. Make all classes implement an interface.

The above solutions are not an option in my case.

Does anybody have another solution to this problem?
In case there is no solution, what is the best way to write an aspect which covers all functions in a project (including external JARs functions)?

Comment: Is pl.codeleak.services.SomeService not your class?

Comment: Those are the 2 options, unless you want to stop using proxies and use compile or load-time weaving.

Comment: @leon, i didnt get your question

Comment: The class that is giving this problem, is it not under your control?

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks, you can add your comment as an answer so i can choose it, if you have some advices about compile or load-time weaving that would be perfect

Comment: @Leon, unfortunately it is not. moreover, there are alot of classes which has the same issue, there is no way to fix them.

Comment: You have crossed into a realm of apsectj that I have no experience with. Have a look at Load Time Weaving as suggested by @M.Deinum http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/aspectj-ltw.html